# Find 3D ellipsoid matlab

Tags: matlab, 3d, ellipse, data-fitting

I have the following problem in Matlab: I have a binary 3D volume (NxNxN) corresponding to a 3D ROI and I want to find the ellipsoid that best fits this ROI. I've found the 3D coordinates of the center, the lengths of the semiaxes in 3D and the 3D angles of the fitting ellipsoid. The resulting vector is something like: [195.1126  169.3114   62.4193   28.2725   23.0191    9.3104   52.9536   -5.7639    1.7606] where the three first elements represent the center coordinates, the elements number 4,5,6 represent the semiaxes radii and the elements number 7,8,9 represent the rotations in degrees in x,y,z respectively. Now I want to find a binary 3D volume (like a 3D matrix: NxNxN, the same size of the original ROI) where 0 is out of the ellipsoid and 1 is the ellipsoid. 
Can anyone help me solving this problem? 
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: The explanations are in the comments

```
     V = [195.1126 169.3114 62.4193,28.2725 23.0191 9.3104,52.9536 -5.7639 1.7606];
 c = V(1:3); % The centroid
 l = V(4:6); % Axis Length
 phi = -V(7:9); % Angles
 E = zeros(512,512,85); % initialize Elipse matrix
 R = rotx(phi(1))*roty(phi(2))*rotz(phi(3)); % Create rotation matrix around phi
 %%
 [X,Y,Z] = meshgrid(1:size(E,2),1:size(E,1),1:size(E,3)); % Create a Grid
 XYZr = ([X(:)-c(1),Y(:)-c(2),Z(:)-c(3)])*R; % rotate Grid and centralize around centroid
 %% Calculate the elipse equation
 inx = (((XYZr(:,1)))./l(1)); % 
 iny = (((XYZr(:,2)))./l(2));
 inz = (((XYZr(:,3)))./l(3));
 ind = [inx,iny,inz];

 E(:) = sum(ind.^2,2)<1;
 %% Display
 figure; imagesc(E(:,:,62));
 figure; imagesc(squeeze(E(:,195,:)));
 figure; imagesc(squeeze(E(170,:,:)));
```

Comment: Hi, well I've tried this but it doesn't work... It gives me wrong results... The ellipsoid is completely wrong, uncentered and with wrong radii. Just one explanation: I initialized E as 512x512x85 matrix because my volume is 512x512x85. If you try with this, it will not work. Do you have any idea on how to solve this?